# magento customer edit for show blank

Tags: magento-1.9

my site was in 1.9.2.2 I update it to 1.9.3.2.

and today I found that

when I open customer edit form in admin side the page is still goes blank.

can anyone help me how to resolve it

Comment: Please check your log files for errors

Comment: please check log files if there is any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its problem of suppe.

so you disable all other third party module and clear cache,report,session in var folder

now you open customer edit page its works fine

Comment: when i disable Amasty_List this extension all works good. thanks @jigs parmar